# How to enable multi-language in gitbook

Tags: gitbook

i looked the answer from  willow

You can setup different SUMMARY.md to setup different titles.
Here is how I setup different titles:

The file structure(find -L):

./LANGS.md
./ch
./ch/README.md
./ch/chapter1.md
./ch/SUMMARY.md
./en
./en/README.md
./en/chapter1.md
./en/SUMMARY.md

LANGS.md :

## Languages

- English
- Chinese

./ch/SUMMARY.md:

## 前言

- 前言
- 第一章

./en/SUMMARY.md :

## Summary

- Introduction
- First Chapter

It works, but the problem is gitbook editor not working.

for example you go to table of contents,  it just shows the English. in other words, you can edit english version now. so it is time to go to Chinese version. i just realize it can not go to Chinese version via editor. it is always English summary and chapter.
looks weird